# Delegate: "System String" cannot converted to type "System.Windows.DependencyProperty"! Why not?

Tags: c#, delegates, dependencies

I am trying to use a delegate for the first time. I used therefore an example with a progressbar which is updating in a loop (works).
Afterwards I try to use the same code but exchanged the progressbar with a TextBox which should display a counter. Unfortunately I get following error:

*Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'.*

Does anyone know why the problem occurs and how I can solve it? Thanks in advance!

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process();
    }

    //Create a Delegate that matches the Signature of the ProgressBar's SetValue method
    private delegate void UpdateSylvacDelegate(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, Object value);



    private void Process()
    {
        //Create a new instance of our ProgressBar Delegate that points
        //  to the ProgressBar's SetValue method.
        var updateTextBoxDelegate = new UpdateSylvacDelegate(myTextBox.SetValue);

        double value = 0;

        //Loop
        do
        {
            string value += Convert.ToString(value);

            /*Update the Value of the ProgressBar:
              1)  Pass the "UpdateSylvacDelegate" delegate that points to the myTextBox.SetValue method
              2)  Set the DispatcherPriority to "Background"
              3)  Pass an Object() Array containing the property to update (ProgressBar.ValueProperty) and the new value */

            Dispatcher.Invoke(updateTextBoxDelegate,
                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                new object[] { TextBox.TextProperty, value });                                
        }
        while (!button2.IsPressed);        
    }



    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

---

### My XML code with 2 Buttons and 1 TextBox:

```
<Window x:Class="test2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Prime Numbers" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="210" Width="472">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="stackPanel1" Width="363" Height="35">
        <Button Content="START" Height="21" Name="button1" Width="69" Click="button1_Click" />
        <TextBox Height="20" Name="myTextBox" Width="114" />
        <Button Content="STOP" Height="22" Name="button2" Width="63" Click="button2_Click" />
        <ProgressBar Height="23" Name="progressBar1" Width="111" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the code for `UpdateSylvacDelegate` since WPF has the attitude to pass errors up. The error occurs somewhere within the `updateTextBoxDelegate` invocation!

And please also paste the code containing self defined dependency properties that might be affected by the delegate as well as the xaml, where the text box resides in!

I will then edit this answer accordingly hopefully with the solution.

Comment: This is the complete code. The UpdateSylvacDelegate is at the moment only a name. If you press the Start-Button the text-box shall count-up until the Stop-Button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem finally. Although it looks easy it tooks a while to see it :)

There was a simple conversion problem between "value" (double) and the TextBox-Propertie which is string.